# Integrating Animate.CSS with Reveal.JS

Tags: javascript, css, animate.css, reveal.js

I've been looking online now for a couple of weeks but can't seem to find a simple solution that works. I want to use Animate.CSS with Reveal.JS

I have the following code already:

```
        <div class="reveal">
        <div class="slides">

        <!-- Intro -->    
            <section data-transition="zoom">
                <div class="headlines-intro">
                    <p class="animated zoomIn">Headlines</p>
                    <h2 class="decorated animated fadeInDown delay-1s"><span><div id="day"></div> <div id="month"></div></span></h2>
                </div><!-- headlines-intro -->
            </section>
        <!-- /Intro -->    

        <!-- Greeting -->
            <section data-transition="zoom" data-autoslide="5000">
                <h1 class="greeting wow hinge">Goedemorgen!</h1>
            </section>
        <!-- /Greeting-->

        </div><!-- /slides -->
    </div><!-- /reveal -->
```

All the animations now trigger when the page loads but I want them only to be loaded when the active section is in view. How do I achieve this? My JS/Jquery skills are very basic.